# I am getting different results, If I read image by base64 vs read from storage

Tags: python, opencv, flask, base64, python-imaging-library

I have a python flask application. I created an `OCR` API.

I am getting correct results, If I read the image from storage like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('test1.jpeg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

But I am getting a bit incorrect results, when I read the same image using Base64. Like this

```
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(request.files['fileToUpload'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: What does *getting a bit incorrect results* mean?

Comment: `rahul` is getting read is `rahal`...like that

Comment: I think I fixed the issue by removing "BGR2RGB" in base64 code.